# Assembly reference warnings?

Tags: asp.net

How can I resolve this assembly reference warnings?

> System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll: warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' matches 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed',
>   you may need to supply runtime policy Newtonsoft.Json.dll: (Location
>   of symbol related to previous warning)

Comment: try to update package. Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `bindingRedirect` to your application's `web.config` file.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Add it to machine.config file